# Flask - ImportError: No module named app

Tags: python, python-import

First I created `__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
```

Then in a separate file, in the same directory, `run.py`

```
from app import app 

app.run(
    debug = True
)
```

When I try to run `run.py`, I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import app 
ImportError: No module named app
```

Comment: I had to place the run.py outside of the app directory to fix this

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`__init__.py` is imported using a directory. if you want to import it as `app` you should put `__init__.py` file in directory named `app`

a better option is just to rename `__init__.py` to `app.py`

Comment: I renamed the directory to 'app', still getting the same error

Comment: don't rename, add a new one and put this file there. (the problem is because `run.py` is also inside the directory)

Comment: but I think that what you really want is to rename the file name to `app.py`

Comment: Could you clarify why I need to make a new folder instead of just renaming the current one?

Comment: it is better to rename.     

`__init__.py` is meant for cases that you want a directory with several files to be a one package.

Comment: i actually just removed run.py from app folder and placed it outside and run it. It worked but i wonder how it worked?

Comment: I renamed it it still getting same error

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer so you are probably doing something else wrong, difficult to help with not enough context, what you files structures? how do you run it? maybe worth creating a new question if this one didn't answers yours

Answer (score 38):

*in case you're still stuck..*

I get the `No module named app` error **only during Debugging, not Running**, in my IDE (VSCode)

That's because I had set `debug=True` (which auto-reloads flask after code changes) in app.py's __main__ :

> app.run(debug=True)

To fix the error, just set it to `False` :

> app.run(debug=False)

Comment: Thank you. Indeed was not that intuitive, using PyCharm.

Comment: Thank you! I also noticed that running app from comand line also fixed the issue: `FLASK_APP=app.py flask run`

Comment: it took me an eternity to find the solution, thank you

Comment: Saved my day... deepest gratitudes, thank you for sharing, brother.

Comment: You saved my day! Any alternatives that I can use `debug=True` when using VSCode debug mode?

Comment: setting debug=True seems pointless as I can step thru my code with it set to false, but Flask crashes immediately if set to true.

Answer (score 19):

This is probably an error in flask application's folder structure.
Anyone looking for a simple beginner-friendly structure for the flask project may find this helpful:

```
   |__movies 
     |__run.py 
     |__app     
        ├── templates
        │   └── index.html
        │   └── signup.html
        └── __init__.py
        └── routes.py
```

Here '*movies*' is the name given for the main application. It contains '*run.py*' and a folder called '*app*'.
'*app*' folder contains all necessary flask files such as '*templates*' folder, '*__init __.py*', and '*routes.py*'.

Contents of:

**run.py**:

```
from app import app
```

**__init__.py**:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

from app import routes


app.run(debug=True)
```

**routes.py**:

```
from app import app

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return "Hello, World!"
```

Comment: How do you run `app` from the command line in this case? The docs suggest `export FLASK_APP="movies/app"; run flask` but it does not work; `flask.cli.NoAppException: Could not import "app".`

Comment: @user5359531 either `export FLASK_APP=main` or `export FLASK_APP=main.py` worked for me with this structure.

Comment: This helps a lot. Somehow, I was trying to do this with an empty `__init__.py`, and what you have put in this file in an `app.py` file, and it was not working. I think I was missing `app.run()` too.

Comment: This is the solution for me. I kept the run.py inside app folder. Changing its directory solved it. Thanks.

Comment: How do you actually run this app and from what path? `run.py `

Answer (score 11):

Ensure to set your PYTHONPATH to the src/ directory as well. Example
`export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/your/src"`

Comment: Thanks, yes, I'm using flask boilerplate and this what actually helped `export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/var/gx/app"`

Comment: in vscode you can put export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/your/src" to launch.json

Answer (score 8):

Your `__init__.py` file needs to go in the folder named app, not the same directory as the run.py file.

`from app import app` is looking in the app folder, so the `__init__.py` file needs to sit in there.

Answer (score 5):

Just rename your file to app.py and it will works.

Answer (score 5):

For me, `export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/your/src && python app/main.py` works

Answer (score 3):

This may be an isolated case, but for me this was a VS Code issue. The "no module found" error would only happen when debug=True.

In VS Code, you can "Run Python File" or "Debug Python File". I was using debug in VS Code AND I had `app.run(debug=True)`. Once I just ran the file normally in VS Code, the problem went away and Flask debugger is working as expected.

I guess it doesn't like 2 layers of Inception!

Answer (score 1):

you are probably running from inside your app folder. Move out to the previous directory and run the command again.

Comment: Indeed. Go to parent folder and call it with e.g. app.run.. If someone is getting this error in FastAPI with Uvicorn, simply run e.g. 'uvicorn app.main:app --host .... -- port....'

Answer (score 1):

If you are having a project structure similar to

```
   |project1
     |README.md
     |project1     
        ├── assets
        │   └── header.png
        └── __init__.py
        └── app.py
```

and

If you are using **VSCode** as your IDE, and errors occur **only during Debugging, not Running**

Summarizing the answers from [d-_-b](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68851873/5087578) and [ckjavi70](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55523930/5087578), 2 solutions are available.

Either in `app.py, if __name__ == "__main__":` , set

```
app.run(debug=False)
```

or in`.vscode/launch.json`, add the following line as part of configurations.

```
"program": "project1/app.py",
"env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/project1"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this as follows -

```
$export FLASK_APP=run

$flask run
```

After executing this command. I don't get any error, my app running smoothly.

Comment: I had a similar issue: 
```python -m FLASK_APP='wsgi_app.py' flask shell ```  -- 

Separating the environment variable worked for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I just want to leave this solution for whom other solutions aren't working.

Assuming here the module "app" is actually referring to your "app.py" source file, in the app.run() ensure to set debug to FALSE i.e. `app.run(debug=False)`. Otherwise `cd` to the folder in which your app.py file is and then run `python app.py`

These are workarounds, but it seems there is a bug in the debug=True flow as old as 2016-17, perhaps it hasn't been fixed yet

Answer (score 0):

for me, the issue was with pycharm IDE, we have set app and the directory containing app as source directory (by right click on directory>Mark directory as>Source Roots)