# in docker python cannot find app

Tags: python-3.x, docker

When I run "`docker-compose up`" on Windows 10 docker client, I get the following errors:

```
counterapp_web_1 |   File "manage.py", line 7, in <module>
counterapp_web_1 |     from app import app
counterapp_db_1 | 2018-01-26T05:09:23.517693Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
counterapp_web_1 | ImportError: No module named 'app',
```

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.4.5-slim

## make a local directory
RUN mkdir /counter_app
ENV PATH=$PATH:/counter_app
ENV PYTHONPATH /counter_app

# set "counter_app" as the working directory from which CMD, RUN, ADD references
WORKDIR /counter_app

# now copy all the files in this directory to /counter_app
ADD . .

# pip install the local requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Listen to port 5000 at runtime
EXPOSE 5000

# Define our command to be run when launching the container
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver"]
```

There is a `manage.py` to call folder `app`, under `app`, there is `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 2):

Double-check is this error on docker run is [because of your directory name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22711701/6309):

> `__init__.py` is imported using a directory. if you want to import it as app you should put `__init__.py` file in directory named `app`
>
> a better option is just to rename `__init__.py` to `app.py`

So a folder named `app`, not `counter_app`.

Comment: tried but failed, now i am trying mongodb, got similar issue, see my code here,