# Python: Unable to import module

Tags: python, flask

I am learning flask from https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/

I have application microblog with filename as microblog.py

```py
from app import app
```

and I have directory named `app` and it contains `__init__.py` with below code

```py
from flask import Flask
from config import Config

app = Flask( __name__ )
app.config.from_object(Config)
from app import routes
```

But when I run `flask run` I am getting error as

```py
ImportError: No module named 'app'
```

I understand like if I  want to indicate a directory as a package then I have to include a `__init__.py` inside the directory and I did so for `app` directory.

Directory structure

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── routes.py
│   └── templates
│       ├── base.html
│       ├── index.html
│       └── login.html
├── config.py
└── microblog.py
```

Full stacktrace

```py
flask run                                       
 * Serving Flask app "microblog.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: While importing "microblog.microblog", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/anaconda3/envs/flask_python3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 235, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "~/learning/migual_flask/microblog/microblog.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import app
ImportError: No module named 'app'
```

And this code worked till recently and suddenly started giving troubles. I am unable to find where this is going wrong.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your directory hierarchy? i.e. where are the files and where are you calling from?

Comment: Why do you have the last line `from app import routes%`? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Maybe it was caused by your directory hierarchy. Try the following link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22711087/flask-importerror-no-module-named-app
and why do you use this?: > from app import routes% Hope this can help you. Have a nice day. :D

Comment: @knh190, I have updated post with directory structure and that % symbol came as part of the `cat` command output.

Comment: Can you post full stacktrace?

Comment: @Kasrâmvd, I have tried all I can but still facing the issue. I am able to import `app` module locally but while importing via `flask run` I am getting the error. Could you please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, from what you post with the hierarchy, it's clear that it should work, but I suspect that you were importing from wrong directory.

Given the directory:

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── routes.py
│   └── templates
│       ├── base.html
│       ├── index.html
│       └── login.html
├── config.py
└── microblog.py
```

Assume you import them from root directory (the "." at the top):

```
$ls                                                                                                                                                        
__init__.py  app          config.py    microblog.py

$ls app
__init__.py  forms.py     routes.py

# which works
>>> import config
>>> import microblog
>>> import app

# and
>>> from app import routes
>>> from app import forms
```

I noticed that you have `app = Flask()` in your `app/__init__.py`, which is a very bad practice which should be avoided as much as possible (what makes you think it's good? I can't think of any), but it works for me:

```
>>> import app
>>> from app import app

# the first app is module
# the second is app = Flask()
# but the second one will overwrite the first one's name
# which is another terrible practice
```

And you can inspect a module:

```
>>> import app
>>> help(app) # app = Flask() is there
```

Comment: I am able to import the module via python console but via `flask run` still facing the same issue.

Comment: @rɑːdʒɑ Your full traceback shows you are importing a module from a class in  `microblog` but you are not showing the source code.

Comment: I have uploaded source code at https://www.sendspace.com/file/nmic8r, Please check.

Comment: And Instead of giving `flask run` I have given `python microblog.py` and its working now.  I have defined a `.flaskenv` file with app name env variable.

Comment: @rɑːdʒɑ Your zip doesn't match your traceback at all! What are you trying to do? I'm completely lost. But since my demo has clearly shown how you can make the import work, I'll close this followup.

Comment: Issue solved, I have removed `__init__.py` file in the parent directory(microblog) and issue resolved.