# No module named app , While running Flask app

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, web-applications, localhost

I'm new to using flask, I tried to execute a basic flask app in Visual-Studio-code . but I'm getting,

> No Module named app

My code is:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello, World"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

path :

[image: Path]

The output terminal:

```
PS C:\Users\Rakesh\Desktop\The project copy>  c:; cd 'c:\Users\Rakesh\Desktop\The project copy'; & 'C:\Python39\python.exe' 'c:\Users\Rakesh\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.5.926500501\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' '52116' '--' 'c:\Users\Rakesh\Desktop\The project copy\env\app.py' 
      
Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)
Environment: production
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
Use a production WSGI server instead.
Debug mode: on
Restarting with stat
No module named app
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22711087/flask-importerror-no-module-named-app Check it here. I also faced the same problem :)

Comment: Note, you should absolutely not put your own py files in the virtual environment folder. This is against python coding conventions and it can make your life a lot harder as weird things can and will happen...

Comment: @EdoAkse     Oh... I moved the app.py out of virtual environment folder , Its working now .Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path of app.py was inside the virtual environment , thus it is not working.
Moving it out of that folder woks.

Answer (score 2):

You probably haven't set the **settings.json** file to allow visual studio code to run the application via virtualenv. Check out this link: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask (spoiler: you have to configure the variabile **python.pythonPath** to specify to vs code where is your python installation).
A possible example of the settings.json file to configure visual studio code to use virtualenv:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "Scripts\\python.exe",
    "files.exclude" : {
        "**/.git" : true,
        "Lib" : true,
        "lib" : true,
        "Include" : true,
        "Scripts" : true,
        "**/__pycache__": true
    }
}
```

P.S. as mentioned by Edo Akse in the comment, it would be good practice not to put your own py files directly in the virtual environment folder

Comment: moving the app.py out of virtual environment folder ,worked for me .Thanks!!