# Flask app won't deploy on ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: python-3.x, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying a flask app on AWS ElasticBeanstalk. I created a new venv from terminal and used `eb init` to create the instance of the application in AWS. I then used `eb create APPNAME-env` to make an environment for the application. On AWS, the health of the site is listed as "OK". However, when I go to the URL, it is a blank white page with no HTML. I looked at the logs, and in `web.stdout.log`, there were several errors. All of them were the same Traceback, from `importlib.import_module()`. Each error said `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application'`. I renamed my main file to `application.py` so there would be a module named `application`, and created a new app instance and new environment. The error persists and the page remains blank. Why does it want a module named `application`, and why isn't it running correctly?

Here's some additional info:

All the Tracebacks were from `load_wsgi()`, by the way.

File structure:
[image]

code of application.py:

```py
from flask import render_template, request, url_for, flash, redirect
from flask import Flask
import datetime
import json

from werkzeug.exceptions import BadRequestKeyError

app=Flask(__name__)
Red_Score=0
Green_Score=0
tossupNum=1
@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def Tossup():
    global Red_Score
    global Green_Score
    global tossupNum
    if request.method=='POST':
        if (int(request.form["Tossup_Green"])<=0 and int(request.form["Tossup_Red"])<=0) and tossupNum==20:
            return redirect(url_for('final'))
        Red_Score+=int(request.form["Tossup_Red"])
        Green_Score+=int(request.form["Tossup_Green"])
        tossupNum+=1
        if int(request.form["Tossup_Red"]) > int(request.form["Tossup_Green"]) and int(request.form["Tossup_Red"])>0:
            return redirect(url_for('redBonus'))
        if int(request.form["Tossup_Red"]) < int(request.form["Tossup_Green"]) and int(request.form["Tossup_Green"])>0:
            return redirect(url_for('greenBonus'))

    else:
        #TODO: It's resetting the numbers when it redirects from bonus, try to insert data into request saying that this isn't an initial load
        #TODO: Try setting the json attribute  of request to store the data
        if tossupNum==1:
            Red_Score=0
            Green_Score=0
            tossupNum=1
    return render_template('Scoresheet_Tossup.html',Red_Score=Red_Score,Green_Score=Green_Score, tossupNum=tossupNum)


def score_from_bonus_data(form):
    result=0
    try:
        if form["Bonus_1"]=='on':
            result+=10
    except BadRequestKeyError:
        pass
    try:
        if form["Bonus_2"]=='on':
            result+=10
    except BadRequestKeyError:
        pass
    try:
        if form["Bonus_2"]=='on':
            result+=10
    except BadRequestKeyError:
        pass
    return result

@app.route('/redBonus',methods=['GET','POST'])
def redBonus():
    global Red_Score
    global Green_Score
    global tossupNum
    #TODO: Make separate redBonus and greenBonus pages so that way you can redirect to specific ones form the tossup page and you only have to deal with one team at a time
    if request.method=='POST':
        Red_Score+=score_from_bonus_data(request.form)
        return redirect(url_for('Tossup'))
    else:
        return render_template('redBonus.html',Red_Score=Red_Score,Green_Score=Green_Score)
@app.route('/greenBonus',methods=['GET','POST'])
def greenBonus():
    global Red_Score
    global Green_Score
    global tossupNum
    #TODO: Make separate redBonus and greenBonus pages so that way you can redirect to specific ones form the tossup page and you only have to deal with one team at a time
    if request.method=='POST':
        Green_Score+=score_from_bonus_data(request.form)
        return redirect(url_for('Tossup'))
    else:
        return render_template('greenBonus.html',Red_Score=Red_Score,Green_Score=Green_Score)


def json_serialize_game(Red_Score, Green_Score):
    now=datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%c')
    return {
        "time":now,
        "Red_Score":Red_Score,
        "Green_Score":Green_Score
    }


@app.route('/final',methods=['GET','POST'])
def final():
    global Red_Score
    global Green_Score
    global tossupNum
    if request.method=='POST':
        with open('GameLog.json', 'r') as json_reader:
            gameLog=json.load(json_reader)
        with open('GameLog.json','w') as json_reader:
            gameLog[datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%c')]={"Red_Score":Red_Score,"Green_Score":Green_Score}
            json.dump(gameLog,json_reader,indent=0)
        tossupNum=1
        return redirect(url_for('Tossup'))
    if Red_Score>Green_Score:
        co_lor="red"
    elif Red_Score<Green_Score:
        co_lor="green"
    else:
        co_lor="gray"
    return render_template('final.html', Red_Score=Red_Score, Green_Score=Green_Score, co_lor=co_lor)
app.run()
```

Contents of `config.yml`:

```yaml
branch-defaults:
  default:
    environment: QBScorer5-env
    group_suffix: null
environment-defaults:
  QBScoringWebsite-dev:
    branch: null
    repository: null
  Qbscoringwebsite-env:
    branch: null
    repository: null
global:
  application_name: QBScorer5
  branch: null
  default_ec2_keyname: null
  default_platform: Python 3.8
  default_region: us-east-2
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: eb-cli
  repository: null
  sc: null
  workspace_type: Application
```

Thanks! Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flask - ImportError: No module named app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22711087/flask-importerror-no-module-named-app)

Comment: I don't think so, for this reason. This website runs fine locally, and like the answer to that question said, I renamed my file to match the module name the error was looking for. This means that there was a module named `application`, but elasticBeanStalk couldn't find it.

Comment: How about changing all of vars `app` to `application` in application.py. This worked for me. 'app' is flask's default way but EB seems using `applicaion`.

Comment: This seemed to eliminate errors, but the page is still blank.