# Why can i not start my gunicorn server in docker? "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'"

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, gunicorn

I am trying to start a dockerized python flask application which i start with:

```
docker build -t python_offerte_test_v1:latest .
docker-compose up web_prod
```

this gives me the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

My coworker says the he runs the exact same code and for him its working. However my /home/code is empty

my folder structure:

```
- DOCKER-PYTHON
    - offerte_scanner
       - server.py
    - app.py
    - docker-compose.yaml
    - Dockerfile
```

My dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8 as python

RUN pip install poetry
RUN mkdir /home/code
ADD ./* /home/code  

# install dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get -y install tesseract-ocr \ 
  && apt-get -y install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6 # required for opencv\
  && apt-get libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
  && apt-get pecl install imagick-6.9 \
  && apt-get docker-php-ext-enable imagick\
  && apt-get install tesseract-ocr-eng  #for english 


#init Poetry
WORKDIR /home/code

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false --local
RUN poetry install --only main
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install ghostscript && apt-get clean


#Set ImageMagick settings with policy.xml
RUN sed -i 's/^.*policy.*coder.*none.*PDF.*//' /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml

COPY policy.xml /etc/ImageMagick-6/
```

my docker-compose yaml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web_prod:
    container_name: python_backend_offerte_scanner
    ports:
     - "5555:5000"
    volumes:
     - .:/code/home
    restart: always
    image: python_offerte_test_v1:latest
    working_dir: /code/home
    environment:
      IP_ELASTICSEARCH: <my ip>
    command: python -m gunicorn -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:5555 app:app
```

my app.py:

```py
from offerte_scanner.server import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

Comment: Change `command: python -m gunicorn -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:5555 app:app` to `command: cd /home/code && python -m gunicorn -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:5555 app:app`
The error you receive is that `app` is not found due you being in the wrong directory. Also your volume mapping is weird. You should only map a configuration file at most not the entire code again. Also you map `/code/home` but in your Dockerfile it is `/home/code`. There is a kogic error

Comment: Yea the `Dockerfile` in the example is copying the files to `/home/code` but the `compose` is setting `working_dir: /code/home`

Comment: i changed this but now i get the error: " no module found: offertescanner"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's a rather concise hint of what is wrong, which wouldn't be too complicated to solve.

In your `main.py`, try changing the `debug` parameter to `False` and see if it works.

this answer comes part from another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22711087/flask-importerror-no-module-named-app).